# Team Foundation Server -> Microsoft Project integration

Tags: tfs, project-management, integration

I am hoping someone here can shed light on my problem.  I am trying to integrate TFS work items and MS Project.  What field is mapped from the work item into the duration column of Project?  I can change the way I am doing this, but, I had created a custom field Work Item field in TFS.  I have the mapping file that TFS uses to map to Project.  Here is my Work Item definition:

```
<FIELD name="EstCodingHours" refname="CustomFields.EstCodingHours" type="Double" 
       reportable="detail">
   <HELPTEXT>Enter estimated number of hours to fix bug</HELPTEXT>
</FIELD>
```

Here is my mapping definition:

```
<Mapping WorkItemTrackingFieldReferenceName="CustomFields.EstCodingHours" 
         ProjectField="pjTaskDuration" ProjectUnits="pjHour" />
```

I can map to other fields such as pjTaskDuration1.  Is pjTaskDuration read only perhaps?  If I can figure out what maps into pjTaskDuration, I can use it instead of my new field EstCodingHours.

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 0):

The TFS out-of-the-box templates don't map the duration field by default.

Wes Macdonald steps through the process of doing such a mapping in a [blog post](http://blogs.like10.com/2008/10/12/tfs-and-ms-project-adding-duration-from-ms-project-into-task-work-item/).